# Fixed the random seed, but unable to reproduce the computational results

Tags: pytorch, random-seed

After fixing the random seed, two separate runs resulted in the same loss for the first batch in each run. However, after the gradient backpropagation, the subsequent batches showed similar but not identical losses, differing only by a few decimal places. These minute differences led to the inability to reproduce my experimental results. Is there a solution to this issue?

Code:

```
seed = args.seed
random.seed(seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False`
```

Loss:
The first run：

```
   2023-11-29 20:58:46,875 - mylogger - INFO - 1 loss is 0.052393343299627304
   2023-11-29 20:58:47,507 - mylogger - INFO - 2 loss is 0.029609812423586845
   2023-11-29 20:58:48,142 - mylogger - INFO - 3 loss is 0.09114564210176468
```

The second run：

```
   2023-11-29 21:00:33,937 - mylogger - INFO - 1 loss is 0.052393343299627304
   2023-11-29 21:00:34,594 - mylogger - INFO - 2 loss is 0.029603876173496246
   2023-11-29 21:00:35,280 - mylogger - INFO - 3 loss is 0.09112581610679626
```

How can I obtain consistent experimental results?